# How to exclude package from grails log4j appender

Tags: grails, log4j, package, appender

I have an appender configured in `Config.groovy` like this:

```
all myLog:['grails.app.controller', 'grails.app.service', 'grails.app.domain', 'grails.app.task'], additivity: false
```

Now there is a special package inside the above packages which I don't want to log, e.g. `grails.app.service.some.service`.

How can I exclude this package from the `myLog` Appender? I already found [this StackOverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140095/exclude-a-class-from-a-log4j-appender), but I don't know how to "translate" this into my grails configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I usually define the log level in Grails differently, something like:

```
  info 'com.opensymphony.oscache'
  warn 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
       'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages' //  GSP
  error 'groovyx.net.http.ParserRegistry'
  debug 'org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS'
```

And to disable the log in a specific package or even a class I do:

```
  off 'com.example.excluded.package'
```

The good thing about this is that you can have full control of the log level per package or even per class if necessary.

Hope this helps!